# Adding points to every "eligible" cluster in PostGIS (ST_ClusterDBSCAN)

Tags: postgis, clustering

I'm currently using `ST_ClusterDBSCAN` in PostGIS to identify similar points for conflation.
(Using clustering to see where multiple entries are within a given range and then manually reviewing & deduplicating.)

This is working well most of the time, but I noticed on the [docs for the function](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClusterDBSCAN.html) it says:

> Note that border geometries may be within eps distance of core geometries in more than one cluster; in this case, either assignment would be correct, and the border geometry will be arbitrarily asssigned to one of the available clusters.

So I think I'm currently missing the case where, e.g. there are points A, B and C evenly spaced 50 meters apart — the function could give me results of:

1. (A, B) / (C)

or

2. (A) / (B, C)

With both cases equally valid from PostGIS point of view. For my use-case though, if B & C were the duplicates in #1, I currently wouldn't find them.

Is it possible to somehow "duplicate" the border geometry here (i.e. something akin to a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` vs an `INNER JOIN`), so it gets added to any 'eligible' cluster to give something like:

- (A, B) / (B, C)

I don't think that's possible from `ST_ClusterDBScan` alone from reading the docs, but wondering if there's a better approach in this case.

Comment: The answer is likely 'not in PostGIS', since you cannot retrieve information about the state of each geometry from the function. Your option here is to implement the DBSCAN algorithm in a custom window function and the PL language of your choice (and output arrays of cluster Ids) - which will be utterly slow compared to the *C* implementation. Changing the native *C* implementation to return arrays of Ids is more intense, and making it finish its looping over clusters, while simple, will increase its execution time to a hard O(n*m).

Comment: On another note: multiplying geometries during clustering is somewhat defeating the purpose. You could, however, cluster as you would, get the minimum bounding circle per cluster, and re-collect geometries (and assign a new array of ids) to all those intersecting (including duplicates in different groups) - not the same results, but an option nonetheless.

Comment: @geozelot yeah I was hoping that I wouldn't need to loop over everything and that applying 'something' to just the border geometries that were in a toss-up would speed up the extra process a little. Thanks for the suggestion on intersecting the cluster geometries — that makes sense, I'll explore that option bit